# AjaxControlToolKit AsyncFileUploader Allowing All Files When AllowedFileTypes has a file type

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

We are having some trouble with the AsyncFileUploade in ASP.NET web forms. Even though we put in an allowed file type, it is allowing all file types.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="asyncFileUploader1" runat="server" UploaderStyle="Modern" AllowedFileTypes="pdf" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" />
```

Comment: plz specify actual issue

Comment: We are only wanting to allow PDFs, but it is allowing all file types through.

Answer (score 1):

**Async**FileUpload does not have AllowedFileTypes property, so this markup affects nothing.

But **Ajax**FileUpload has it, so you use AjaxFileUpload and successfully set AllowedFileTypes property to "pdf".